# Calling non-static void from another cs file

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I probably know somebody asked the same thing here before. I found some info on google and here on stackoverflow , but I just can't get it to work properly.

I need to call a non-static void (MainPage.cs / class MainPage) .

```
public async void UploadThat() 
        {
         .
         .
         .
         .
     Messagebox.Show("Hello there!");
        }
```

from a another cs file (WebServer.cs).

**I tried to do it like this in Webserver.cs file:**

```
using MainPage;
    .
    .
    .    
public MainPage test;
```

and than call: `test.UploadThat();`

It complied my app successfully, but it does not work.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Use the debugger... is `test.UploadThat();` actually being invoked, or not? If it is invoked, what is going on inside `UploadThat()`? Only one way to find out - use breakpoints as well as single-step through your code...

Comment: Did you instansiate `MainPage`?

Comment: Sadly It does NOT gets invoked. It's not stopping on breakpoint i have in UploadThat(). In UploadThat() there is just a simple code to write text to an IsolatedStorage on my Windows Phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this. Here are the two most common:

- call the method directly; since the method is not static, you need a reference to the `MainPage` instance. That instance could be passed to the constructor of `WebServer`, and stored as a field. Note that this approach causes high coupling between the classes, which is usually not desirable.

  in WebServer.cs:

  ```
  private readonly MainPage _mainPage;

  public WebServer(MainPage mainPage)
  {
      _mainPage = mainPage;
  }

  ...

      _mainPage.UploadThat();
  ```

  in MainPage.cs:

  ```
  WebServer ws = new WebServer(this);
  ```
- expose an event in the `WebServer` class; have `MainPage` handle this event by calling `UploadThat`; when `WebServer` wants to call `UploadThat`, it just raises the event, and `MainPage` takes care of it. This way, `WebServer` doesn't have to know anything about `MainPage`.

  in WebServer.cs:

  ```
  public event EventHandler UploadRequested;
  private void OnUploadRequested()
  {
      EventHandler handler = UploadRequested;
      if (handler != null)
          handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }

  ...

  // instead of calling UploadThat directly
  OnUploadRequested();
  ```

  in MainPage.cs:

  ```
  WebServer ws = new WebServer();
  ws.UploadRequested += ws_UploadRequested;

  ...

  private void ws_UploadRequested(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      UploadThat();
  }
  ```

As a side note, you should avoid `async void` methods, except for event handlers or method overrides. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) explains why.

Comment: Thank you for a response, really appreciate it. Can you show me a example of calling the method directly on a piece of the code ? Thanks again :)

Comment: @OliŘeháček, I have updated my answer with examples. However I strongly advise you to use the second approach, as it reduces coupling between the classes.